# Mathematical proof question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be integers. Prove that if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a$ divides every linear combination of the form ax + by, where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$a|b $ means $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = na$. Similarly, $a|c $ means $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = ma$.

Thus $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, 
$$ bx + cy = a(nx + my).$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is close for addition and multiplication, $nx + my \in \mathbb{Z}$, so 
$$ a |bx + cy , \, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2.$$